# how to define which module to fire first in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

How to define which module to fire first in Zend Framework 2, I need this as I have two modules created 1>front and another is 2>admin  and my main folder is mysite , so my requirement is when I fire:

```
  http://example.com
```

it should fire front module.

I'm unable to figure how to call the front modules controller.

I'm using Zend Framework 2 for first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any module.config.php -

set the route as -

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/',        // due to '/' - http://mysite.net will call the below module's controller - action
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller', //Set the front module name here
                    'controller' => 'Index',  //set the front module's controller name
                    'action' => 'index', //here the action name
                ),
            ),
        ),
        //..... some other routes
   )
)
```

It will work fine. Let us know the result to help further.

Comment: @Soumik than you should approve this answer.

Comment: @tasmaiski how to approve this answer , no idea sir jee.

Comment: @Soumik, if you find the answer helpful then you can up-vote it by clicking the up-arrow `(^)` available on the left of the answer. And if you find the answer to be exactly what your looking for (not just helpful but exact), then you can click the `tick` on the left on the answer.

Comment: @KunalDethe I have a query , the solution you gave me works but since i have searching in home page so i need search parameter ,along with page parameter to pass over url , how to do that , and also i need to redirect to a controller how to give that code since "/" is used , please help me.